# Newest Ubuntu upgrade won't let me change the background image

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS this morning. First thing I noticed was that my background image had change. No problem, I go into settings/background and change it. A few seconds later it changes back to the default image. Hmm Okay, I go into Shotwell, import a few photos and select, 'set as desktop slideshow', and my background changes. But after a few seconds it changes back to that default image. Alright, let me try this again. I go into Tweaks, and change the background image there. It changes but once again a few seconds later it changes back to the default image.

I'm not sure what else to try. It's very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install the DCONF editor for Gnome Settings.

Make sure you copy the pictures to your Documents or Pictures folder.

Open Dconf, go to the Background settings, picture URL and point that to your photo.

I do this in Ubuntu 20.04 and the background sticks.

[image]

Comment: I am curious if Dconf Configuration has worked for you. It certainly works here.